bounded operator restrict on dense subspace is injective, does the adjoint has dense range?
For a densely-defined operator $T$ in Hilbert space $H$, it is known that $ker(T^{*})=im(T)^{\perp}$. Assume $S$ is an bounded operator of $H$ and $S$ is injective on a dense subspace. My question is if its adjoint $S^{*}$ has dense range.
I think the answer is yes, because since $S$ and $S^{*}$ is bounded, even we restrict $S$ on a (proper) dense subspace $D$, $S^{*}$ is still the adjoint of $S|_{D}$ by the uniqueness of adjoint, so by the above fact with replacing $T=S^{*}$, $S^{*}$ should has dense range. But at the same time I feel uncomfortable as there is example that bounded operator on Hilbert space is injective on dense subspace but not injective on the whole space.

Another pretty simple example: consider  $\mathcal{H}=\ell^2$ and the linear subspace $V$ spanned by $e_k,$ $k\ge 2,$ and $v=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}e_k,$ where $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ denotes the standard basis in $\ell^2.$  The space $V$ is dense and does not contain $e_1.$ The orthogonal projection onto $e_1^\perp$ is thus injective on $V,$ however its range is not dense.
Actually every infinite dimensional bounded linear operator on a separable Hilbert space is injective on a dense subspace. Indeed, I will restrict to the case when $\dim\ker A=\infty.$ The case $\dim\ker A<\infty$ can be treated in a similar way. Let $\{f_{k,n}\}_{k,n=1}^\infty $ denote an orthonormal basis of $(\ker A)^\perp$ and $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ an orthonormal basis of $\ker A$. Let $V$ be the subspace spanned by $\{f_{k,n}\}_{k,n=1}^\infty$ and the elements
$$v_n=e_n+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}f_{k,n}$$ The subspace $V$ is dense, as the elements $e_n$ belong to the closure of $V,$ namely $e_n=\lim_{K\to\infty}\left [v_n-\sum_{k=1}^K2^{-n}f_{k,n}\right].$ Moreover $V$ does not contain any element in $\ker A$ (cf. the spoiler). Thus $A$ is injective on $V.$

 Assume $$\sum_{j=1}^J\alpha_j f_{k_j,n_j}+\sum_{n=1}^N\beta_n\left [e_n+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}f_{k,n}\right ]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \gamma_ne_n$$The right hand side is orthogonal to $f_{k,n}$ for $k>\max k_j.$ Hence $\beta_n=0$ for all $n.$ This implies $\alpha_j=0$ and $\gamma_n=0$ for all $j$ and all $n.$


Does "infinite dimensional bounded linear operator" mean for you that the operator has infinite dimensional range? Also how would I prove this statement?

@SeverinSchraven Yes, infinite dimensional range. I guess the proof can be performed along the lines of the example.

Thanks, I just saw your edit. Yes, for a separable Hilbert space I can believe that we can make your trick work.

I have just extended the answer, hopefully correct.

You already know there exists $S$ that’s not injective but injective on a dense subspace. You also know that $S^\ast$ has range the orthogonal complement of the kernel of $S$, so as $S$ is not injective, the range of $S^\ast$ cannot be dense. As a concrete example, let $S$ be multiplication by the indicator function of a fat Cantor set on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then $S$ is injective on compactly supported continuous functions, which is dense. But $S^\ast = S$ certainly does not have dense range - it is an orthogonal projection onto a proper subspace.

The reason your argument does not work is because, if you choose $T = S^\ast$, then $T^\ast = S^{\ast\ast}$, which is the closure of $S$, not $S$ itself. So what it tells you is that $\text{ker}(\bar{S}) = \text{im}(S^\ast)^\perp$, so if $S$ is bounded, you have to consider the everywhere defined closure of $S$, not just restricted to a dense subspace.
